# Rotating spherical shells doesn't change volume

Tags: measure-theory, differential-geometry, lie-groups

Let $\gamma\colon \mathbb R\to SO(n)$ be a path (but not necessarily a one-parameter group). It leads to a diffeomorphism $f\colon \mathbb R^n\to \mathbb R^n$

$$f(x) = \gamma\left(\lVert x \rVert^2\right)x,$$

which rotates around the origin every spherical shell, according to a rotation specified by the distance from the origin.

I wonder if $f$ is volume-preserving, i.e., at every point $\vert\det f'(x)\vert = 1$.

This is what I know:

1. Proof that $f$ is a diffeomorphism is easy, as its inverse is just $x\mapsto \gamma(\lVert x \rVert ^2)^{-1}x$.
2. For $n=2$ this is easy, but tedious – $SO(2)\simeq S^1$ and I was able to write a general $\gamma$ as $t\mapsto \exp(i u(t))$ for some function $u\colon \mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ and verify the required identity manually.
3. I'm speculating now, but the Borel algebra on $\mathbb R^n$ has a basis being (a high-dimensional analogue of) a steradian spanned between radii $r_1$ and $r_2$. I think it may be possible to prove using Fubini's theorem something like the Cavalieri's principle – the area of each "steradian" doesn't change (as we are rigidly rotating it by an element of $SO(n)$) so that the total volume doesn't change either. (And pass from this basis to arbitrary Borel sets). I however wasn't able to fill in the details and turn this intuition into a formal proof.
4. In general, $f'(x) \neq \gamma(\lVert x \rVert^2)$, but I believe that $\det f'(x) = 1 = \det \gamma(\lVert x \rVert^2)$.

Comment: Why not compute the derivative directly? I get $$f'(x) = 2\gamma'(||x||^2)xx^T + \gamma(||x||^2)$$ While possible with an appropriately fine tuned map, it seems like it is not true in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After fixing a point of interest $x_0,$ we can without loss of generality assume that $\gamma(\|x_0\|^2)$ is the identity (since applying a fixed rotation to the whole setup will preserve all determinants). If we work in an orthonormal basis with $e_1 = x_0/\|x_0\|$, the derivative in Ninad's comment can be written as a block matrix

$$f'(x_0) = \left(\begin{array}{@{}c|c@{}}
    c & 0\\\hline
    \mathbf v & \mathbb I
  \end{array}\right)$$

where the first column is
$f'(x_0)e_1 = e_1 + 2 \|x_0\|^2 \gamma'(\|x_0\|^2)e_1.$

Thus we see that the determinant is $c = e_1^T f'(x_0)e_1$. Since $\gamma'(\|x_0\|)^2 \in \mathfrak{so}_n$, it is antisymmetric, and thus $e_1^T \gamma'(\|x_0^2\|)e_1 = 0,$ so

$$ \det f = e_1^T \left(e_1 + 2 \|x_0\|^2 \gamma'(\|x_0\|^2)e_1\right) = e_1^Te_1 = 1$$ as desired.